# Nuxt3 static generate nitro

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to get my nuxt3 app running with "npm run generate" using nuxt3/Vue3.
When I go to a dynamic route url like "https://mywebsite.com/zzz/xxx", I get the following error messages in Chrome in my production environment (not development):

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

and :

```
entry.bfc08d14.js:5 [nuxt] Cannot load payload  /zzz/xxx/_payload.js TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://mywebsite.com/zzz/xxx/_payload.js
```

Is it a normal behavior for a dynamic route?

How can I build a payload file for those 30k+ dynamic pages? I tried with an example in my nuxt.config.js file with no success:

```
nitro: {
        prerender: {
          routes: ['/zzz/xxx']
        }
      }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you preview your app?

Comment: I’m using npm run dev and it is working fine. The problem is ssr related

Comment: `npm run dev` is for dev. What do you use to **preview** the app? (once it's generated)

Comment: I’m using npm run generate and upload the output of « public » directory to my apache server

Comment: This is not enough. Let's focus on making it work locally at first (before going to Apache). Please generate it again and read the given prompt (should recommend you using `serve` command) to preview it locally. Does it work that way? PS: you will mainly need to still run a server to serve your app on Apache.